# NetlinkListener and NetlinkEvent error messages

Tags: android, sockets, android-logcat, motorola, netlink

My application does not break during Runtime. However, the following error messages always show up

> NetlinkListener: ignoring non-kernel netlink multicast message
>   NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UDEV_LOG' not found

The app I'm developing uses sockets to receive packages from a specific IP source (with specific enabled port number). I set up a set of Log outputs (I even tried  'System.out.println' calls) to verify the data flow and everything seems to be fine.

Can anyone tell me what those errors messages are exactly related to?

The device I'm using for testing purposes is a Motorola Atrix 4G (MB860) with the latest OTA update (Android 2.3.6). Because of compatibility issues, all the development we do have to be done using API 8 (or earlier).

Comment: I get this all the time on my 2.3.6 Motorola Atrix. Must be a thing with clunky Motorola.

Comment: Also happens in Moto E Gen 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having the same issue, it's a bug on 2.3.6, reported on Motorola and Android.

[Link to Android bug report.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32339&q=3g&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

In the bug report, I added the info for my phone plus the search I did on the forums. If anyone has the same issue please add a star and/or comment to make them know that the issue exists and it's not related to only one country/cell provider.

Comment: please provide a link to bug reports, if possible.

Comment: Alejandro, thanks for the info you posted. Perhaps, the issue is not related to a single country. However, we got two different flavors of Android OS mods. One is set for the German market and the other for Latin American consumers. The latest one is the one having issues.

Comment: well, i see that the issue is being reported on the US too, also not only for motorola devices, please check the links i posted on the bug report

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be something else on the Atrix.  I have an Atrix and looking at LogCat those errors come out a lot, so its not your app.

Comment: Me too. Like, tons of them when I have my atrix hooked up. Boo.

Answer (score 2):

After I rooted my Atrix phone I noticed this problem.  Logcat outputs it constantly :(