# NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found

Tags: android, motorola, netlink

My application does not break during Runtime. However, the following error messages always show up

```
E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
```

this log print continuously, i did not understand and what is cause of this error,**Can anyone of you guys tell me what those errors** messages are exactly related to?

> Device is moto g3.

Appreciate any help you can provide me with.

I found some link but there issue is

```
NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UDEV_LOG' not found
```

Comment: Also happens in Moto E Gen 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetlinkListener and NetlinkEvent error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318938/netlinklistener-and-netlinkevent-error-messages)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem of the "NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found" with the log print loop.

I figured it was something related to my Wi-Fi connection. What solved my problem was to toggle OFF the "Airplane Mode" 
(basically when I had Wi-Fi and Airplane Mode ON this error occurred)

I hope this helps you

Comment: i checked with moto team they informed this is not an issue, its only info uid param is missing, this issue came when your router not share his identity.

Comment: @YogeshRathi - Is this question/answer specifically about a Motorola phone?

Comment: Yes. I got only in Motorola

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
cpp.getFullNumberWithPlus()
```

instead of:

```
cpp.getFullNumber
```

Or check you had added:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`. It might be helpful for you.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation or an example. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer