# NetLinkEvent - Parameter 'STATE' not found in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The app(Android) runs properly but got an error saying

> NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'STATE' not found

which was triggered from a method() I created , below is the method :

```
public void cleanMapAndUpdateUI() {
    if (poiMiniBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
        fabGpsAndLocation.startAnimation(scaleUpFadeIn);
        fabGpsAndLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        poiMiniBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    }
    selectedChip.setChipBackgroundColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)));
    selectedChip = null;
    isChipSelected = false;
    gMap.clear();
    searchTxtBtn.setText("");
    searchTxtBtn.setHint(R.string.search_here);
    officialAppIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    mapLayerImgBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    isMarkerAdded = false;
    getCurrentLocation();
}
```

**Logcat**

> 2021-12-24 19:37:23.947 1088-1283/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'STATE' not found
> at com.krishan.officialexploremanipurapp.ui.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:1010)
> 2021-12-24 19:55:36.820 1964-1996/? E/KernelCpuUidUserSysTimeReader: Negative user/sys time delta for UID=10048
> Prev times: u=604850000 s=265700000 Curr times: u=604740000 s=265600000
> 2021-12-24 20:41:34.800 1964-3416/? W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.krishan.officialexploremanipurapp/.ui.MainActivity
> 2021-12-24 20:41:35.085 1964-4546/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{8fe25a3 u0 com.krishan.officialexploremanipurapp/com.krishan.officialexploremanipurapp.ui.MainActivity}

In Logcat is say ***onClick(MainActivity.java:1010)** which is the line of `cleanMapAndUpdateUI(){..}`

If anyone have gone through this problem , please help me out :)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

its only info uid param is missing, this issue came when your router not share his identity, and this might be help you to solve the problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54385473/17562398

Comment: yea, I have found alot on uid param is missing but not on "STATE" . I'll check it out . Thanks for your time.

Comment: eh, nvm heheheh